# Add row number to existing column with additional criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a corresponding data structure:

```
ItemId ItemDescription
1      blahblah
2      blahblah
3      foobar
4      foobar
5      lorem
6      blahblah
7      lorem
```

I wanna append a unique postfix to ItemDescription based on  ItemId order and groupped by ItemDescription value.

Desired result:

```
ItemId ItemDescription
1      blahblah1
2      blahblah2
3      foobar1
4      foobar2
5      lorem1
6      blahblah3
7      lorem2
```

I had a successful try with a fixed ItemDescription:

```
update item
set ItemDescription = ItemDescription + cast(row_num as varchar)
from (select ItemDescription , row_number() over (order by i.ItemId) as row_num 
      from Item i
      where i.ItemDescription = 'lorem') item
```

But there are thousands of them, so I wanna do it in a single script / couple of them. Looks like I have to use a `row_number()` function with some kind of nested selects, but no luck so far.

Comment: If you *don't* filter the items and use `partition by `itemdescription` instead, you'll get a row number per description. You don't need to use a loop or nested selects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `partition by`:

```
update item
    set ItemDescription = concat(ItemDescription, row_num)
from (select ItemDescription,
             row_number() over (partition by i.ItemDescription order by i.ItemId) as row_num 
      from Item i
     ) item;
```

Note that you should not use `varchar` without a length specification.  To get around this, I used `concat()` rather than `+`, because it will convert the number to a string.